# Best way to load non-JS scripts from an assets folder: getElementbyID vs fetch, remote files or write their content in the html?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, jekyll

For context:

I'm rather new to this section of Javascript (I'm mostly from a C++ background) and I'm trying to implement webGL in my Jekyll generated website.

I'm following the great tutorial at: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html but I've reached a bit of a problem. In the tutorial they basically type everything directly into the html which is a less than ideal solution for bigger projects, so I've put them in separate .glsl files in the _assets folder in my jekyll build.

**Eitherway, now for the important bit:**

I need to load the content of a file into a variable in javascript.

I've tried first to do this on my html:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="notjs" src="/assets/2dVertexShader.glsl"   id="2dVertexShader"  ></script>
<script type="notjs" src="/assets/2dFragmentShader.glsl" id="2dFragmentShader"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/test.js" ></script>
```

Matched with, on that javascript:

```
var vertexShaderSource = document.getElementById("2dVertexShader").text;
var fragmentShaderSource = document.getElementById("2dFragmentShader").text;
```

Now this isn't working. I cannot tell why. I've also tried using `fetch('/assets/2dVertexShader.glsl')` but this is another can of worms since I only get a promise back and, as far as I can tell, forces me to encapsulate most of the relevant code into async function so I can use await. Less than ideal.

I can tell you that actually typing the content of the glsl scripts inside the `<script>` tags in html has worked but this is not ideal. At all.

I can paste the rest of my html and my js and my glsl stuff but I highly doubt it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your question might get closed as mostly opinion but....

My suggestion, use es6 modules with multi-line templates.

```
// some-vs-shader.glsl
export default `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
```

Then you can import in some other script like this

```
import someVertexShaderSource from './some-vs-shader.glsl';
```

And if you want you can later run rollup or webpack or parcel to read through your code and generate one large file that downloads faster.

[This is what three.js does](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib).

note that in order to use the `import` keyword you need to use `type="module"` as in either

```
<script type="module" src="somescript.js"><script>
```

or inline

```
<script type="module">
import someVertexShaderSource from './some-vs-shader.glsl';
...
</script>
```

Note: I threw together [a working example](https://glitch.com/~using-import-for-glsl). I had to name the files so they end in `.js` because glitch.com's server sends the wrong `Content-Type` header otherwise. So you have to decide if you want end your files to end in `.glsl` you'll need to find out how to configure your server to send the correct content-type header.

As for your question of why

```
<script type="notjs" src="/assets/2dVertexShader.glsl"   id="2dVertexShader"  ></script>
```

doesn't work, TL;DR It's because the spec says it's not supposed to.